# Mock an out parameter with moq or rhino mock or something else

Tags: unit-testing, parameters, mocking

I tried with NMock2 but I get TypeLoadExceptions when trying to pass the mocks into the constructor, also I saw TypeMock can do that but it costs 80$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found out myself, you can actually do that with Moq, it's like this:

```
var info = new Info { stuff = 1 };

textReader.Setup(o => o.Read<CandidateCsv>("", out info));
```

that's it :)

Comment: That's true, but you can't have Moq change the value of info when Read is executed.

Answer (score 3):

Moq [does not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068095/assigning-out-ref-parameters-in-moq) support mocking out/ref parameters, but you can do it using Rhino Mocks using OutRef, which accepts one argument for each out/ref parameter in the method.

```cs
MockRepository mockRepository = new MockRepository();

// IService.Execute(out int result);
var mock = mockRepository.CreateStub<IService>();

int mockResult; // Still needed in order for Execute to compile

mock.Setup(x => x.Execute(out mockResult)).OutRef(5);
mock.Replay();

int result;

mock.Execute(out result);

Assert.AreEqual(5, result);
```

Comment: This is no longer correct. Moq does support out/ref parameters. See http://code.google.com/p/moq/wiki/QuickStart

Comment: @TrueWill - The level of support has not changed. You still cannot expect a method call with a certain `ref` argument and then specify that that argument be changed to another value.

Comment: true, but you can simply declare a new mock. A limitation on what can be changed after setup is not the same thing as lack of support for mocking out/ref parameters.

Comment: @TrueWill - I disagree, the aforementioned scenario is not possible making `ref` parameters, for all intents an purposes, unsupported. `out` parameters are supported, though, granted.

Comment: -1 for the fact which is stated in Chuck Norris. I use that code often.

Comment: @Floradu88 - the parameters cannot be mocked. Fot example, you cannot change the value of a ref parameter based on it's initial value.

Comment: Yeah but the value you need is the out value which you can set. That if the whole purpose of out.