# Assigning out parameters in Moq for methods that return void

Tags: c#, .net, generics, moq

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068095/assigning-out-ref-parameters-in-moq), I found an [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19598345/1591992) that seems to be the best way to solve the problem to me.

The provided code assumes that the function that is mocked returns a value:

```
bool SomeFunc(out ISomeObject o);
```

However, the object I want to mock has an out function as follows:

```
void SomeFunc(out ISomeObject o);
```

The relevant code fragment from the mentioned answer:

```
public delegate void OutAction<TOut>(out TOut outVal);

public static IReturnsThrows<TMock, TReturn> OutCallback<TMock, TReturn, TOut>(
    this ICallback<TMock, TReturn> mock, OutAction<TOut> action)
    where TMock : class
{
    // ...
}
```

Void is not a valid type for TReturn. So I believe I would have to somehow adapt this code to get it to work with methods returning void. But how?

Comment: What errors did you get? What's the issue?

Comment: I've updated my answer [here][1] with support for void-return functions.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19598345/33791

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Maybe you simply need this:

```
ISomeObject so = new SomeObject(...);
yourMock.Setup(x => x.SomeFunc(out so));
```

Then when you use `yourMock.Object` in the code you test, the `so` instance will "magically" come out as the `out` parameter.

It is a little non-intuitive ("out is in"), but it works.

---

Addition: Not sure I understand the scenario. The following complete program works fine:

```
static class Program
{
  static void Main()
  {
    // test the instance method from 'TestObject', passing in a mock as 'mftbt' argument
    var testObj = new TestObject();

    var myMock = new Mock<IMyFaceToBeTested>();
    IMyArgFace magicalOut = new MyClass();
    myMock.Setup(x => x.MyMethod(out magicalOut)).Returns(true);

    testObj.TestMe(myMock.Object);
  }
}

class TestObject
{
  internal void TestMe(IMyFaceToBeTested mftbt)
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Now code to be tested is running. Calling the method");
    IMyArgFace maf; // not assigned here, out parameter
    bool result = mftbt.MyMethod(out maf);
    Console.WriteLine("Method call completed");
    Console.WriteLine("Return value was: " + result);
    if (maf == null)
    {
      Console.WriteLine("out parameter was set to null");
    }
    else
    {
      Console.WriteLine("out parameter non-null; has runtime type: " + maf.GetType());
    }
  }
}

public interface IMyFaceToBeTested
{
  bool MyMethod(out IMyArgFace maf);
}
public interface IMyArgFace
{
}
class MyClass : IMyArgFace
{
}
```

Please indicate how your situation is different, by using the names of the classes and interfaces from my example.

Comment: That's not the answer. As in the linked question, the problem is that the code under test will call the function with an out-reference, and I need to set the correct object to the passed-in pointer.

Comment: Have you tried it? It works "magically". I checked the linked thread, and there is [a massively upvoted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3135677/1336654) which suggests the same "solution" as I do.

Comment: Yes I did. Please read the comments to that answer. The problem is assignment, and that solution does not solve that problem.

Comment: @Wilbert Assignment how? See my example in the updated answer.

Comment: See here: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/7544053. The problem is that within the moq.Setup method, I want to assign some value to the out parameter. The actual pointer to the param is provided by the class under test. Your solution works if the out-pointer is provided by the test.

Comment: @Wilbert Then substitute the problematic line with: `b_mock.Setup(b => b.Get(out a));` and it works. It seems magical, but it is that simple.

Comment: Ok I feel like an idiot now. To think it was so simple all along.. :) Thanks a lot!