# How do I mock an out parameter with Moq?

Tags: .net, moq

I have a class that I am testing.  This class uses takes in an interface as a constructor parameter.  This interface has a method that has an out parameter.

What I want to do is mock this method so that the out parameter is always a particular value.

How can this be done?

Comment: This question may be of help: [Assigning out/ref parameters in Moq](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068095/assigning-out-ref-parameters-in-moq)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To do this just create a local with the desired value and use that in the `out` position.

```
int theValue = 42;
Mock<ITarget> target = ...;
target.Setup(x => x.TheMethod(out theValue));
```