# How to mock a melthod with out paramter in Moq AND fill the out

Tags: unit-testing, nunit, moq

I have see several questions here in Stackoverflow about out parameters in MOQ, my question is how fill this parameter: Lets to code:

```
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage Send(SmsMoRequest sms)
{
    if (sms == null)
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);

    SmsMoResponse response;
    _messageService.Process(sms, out response);
    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, response.ToString());
}
```

I want to test this post:

```
[Test]
public void Should_Status_Be_Create_With_Valid_XML()
{
    // Arrange
    var messageServiceMoq = new Mock<IMessageService>();
    SmsMoResponse response;
    messageServiceMoq.Setup(mock => mock.Process(It.IsNotNull<SmsMoRequest>(), out response));
    _kernel.Bind<IMessageService>().ToConstant(messageServiceMoq.Object);
    var client = new HttpClient(_httpServer) { BaseAddress = new Uri(Url) };

    // Act
    using (var response = client.PostAsync(string.Format("Api/Messages/Send"), ValidContent()).Result)
    {
        // Asserts
        response.IsSuccessStatusCode.Should().BeTrue();
        response.StatusCode.Should().Be(HttpStatusCode.Created);
    }
}
```

### Problem

My `response` object in Send method (POST) is used in post response but the `_messageService.Process` is responsible to fill the `response` object.
In test method `Should_Status_Be_Create_With_Valid_XML` I mock `_messageService.Process` and `response` object is not fill ocorr error `Null reference` in  `Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, response.ToString());`

`response` is null!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course `response` is null, there's no code anywhere that would set it to anything (in your service method or your mock).

Since you're mocking the method that would usually fill it in, it's up to *you* to specify how it is set.  You should fill in the object before calling `Setup` with what you *expect* to be the value when that method is called.

Also, see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1068095/1698557) for more info.

Comment: The `response` object declared in `Send` method is null.
Even if I initialize and fill it in `Should_Status_Be_Create_With_Valid_XML` test method, in `Send` method it will be null.

Consequently the `response.ToString()` it will generate a Null reference error.

Comment: Sorry.. you're right, I have to set it on my test with results expected.