# Moq testing void methods with out parameters

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

Hi Please let me know how to write the moq unit test case for the below method.Any help would be appreciated .Thanks in advance.

```
public void ConstructAddMappingQuery(IAnnotationMapping annotationMappings, 
                                     out string commandText, 
                                     out Dictionary<string, dynamic> parameters)
{
   commandText =@"Insert Into AnnotationMapping Values 
                 (@AnnotationSetupId, @WordToAnnotate, 
                  @Annotation, @CreatedDttm, @CreatedUserId, @ModifiedDate, 
                  @ModifiedUserId, @IsActive)";

   parameters = new Dictionary<string, dynamic>();
   parameters.Add("@WordToAnnotate", annotationMappings.WordToAnnotate);
   parameters.Add("@Annotation", annotationMappings.Annotation);
   parameters.Add("@ModifiedDate", annotationMappings.ModifiedDate);
   parameters.Add("@ModifiedUserId", annotationMappings.ModifiedUserId);
   parameters.Add("@AnnotationSetupId", annotationMappings.AnnotationSetupId);
   parameters.Add("@CreatedDttm", annotationMappings.CreatedDttm);
   parameters.Add("@CreatedUserId", annotationMappings.CreatedUserId);
   parameters.Add("@IsActive", 1);
}
```

Looking for the whole method not the stub.Cheers!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Please edit you question first, check this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: Does this work for you : http://stackoverflow.com/a/3135677 ?

Comment: Please [edit] your post to clarify what particular help you are looking for and what you want to test. In current state this is next level of "write code for me" request (usually such request at least have information on what should be done...)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Assigning out/ref parameters in Moq](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068095/assigning-out-ref-parameters-in-moq)

Comment: Why do you think you need Moq here?

Comment: I have to increase the code coverage of my project as of now these set of statements are not covered

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a class like

```
public class AnnotationMappingQueryBuilder {
    public void ConstructAddMappingQuery(IAnnotationMapping annotationMappings,
                                 out string commandText,
                                 out Dictionary<string, dynamic> parameters) {
        commandText = @"Insert Into AnnotationMapping Values 
             (@AnnotationSetupId, @WordToAnnotate, 
              @Annotation, @CreatedDttm, @CreatedUserId, @ModifiedDate, 
              @ModifiedUserId, @IsActive)";

        parameters = new Dictionary<string, dynamic>();
        parameters.Add("@WordToAnnotate", annotationMappings.WordToAnnotate);
        parameters.Add("@Annotation", annotationMappings.Annotation);
        parameters.Add("@ModifiedDate", annotationMappings.ModifiedDate);
        parameters.Add("@ModifiedUserId", annotationMappings.ModifiedUserId);
        parameters.Add("@AnnotationSetupId", annotationMappings.AnnotationSetupId);
        parameters.Add("@CreatedDttm", annotationMappings.CreatedDttm);
        parameters.Add("@CreatedUserId", annotationMappings.CreatedUserId);
        parameters.Add("@IsActive", 1);
    }
}
```

You will only need Moq for the interface. A test could look like this.

```
[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1 {
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1() {

        //Arrange
        var mock = Mock.Of<IAnnotationMapping>();

        var expectedCommandText = @"Insert Into AnnotationMapping Values 
             (@AnnotationSetupId, @WordToAnnotate, 
              @Annotation, @CreatedDttm, @CreatedUserId, @ModifiedDate, 
              @ModifiedUserId, @IsActive)";
        string commandText = null;
        Dictionary<string, dynamic> parameters = null;
        int expectedParameterCount = 8;
        var sut = new AnnotationMappingQueryBuilder();

        //Act
        sut.ConstructAddMappingQuery(mock, out commandText, out parameters);

        //Assert
        Assert.IsNotNull(commandText);
        Assert.AreEqual(expectedCommandText, commandText);

        Assert.IsNotNull(parameters);
        Assert.AreEqual(expectedParameterCount, parameters.Count);
        ///what ever else you want to assert for parameters
    }
}
```