# Problems with Ref Keyword in MOQ

Tags: .net, automated-tests, moq

Hoping someone can help me.

I am trying to test a method (Outer Method) that has as a dependency a class that invokes another method (Inner Method).  This inner method takes a Boolean as a Ref Parameter, and my problem is that I am so far been unable to control this Boolean Ref parameter.

(Note-The code shown below has been written for the purpose of illustrating the problem and is not what the code really looks like).

The MOQ documentation from here - https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart
gives an overview of dealing with Ref/Out parms but I have not found it that helpful.

I tried an example that works (which I found here - [Assigning out/ref parameters in Moq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068095/assigning-out-ref-parameters-in-moq))

```
public interface IService
{
    void DoSomething(out string a);
}

[Test]
public void Test()
{
    var service = new Mock<IService>();
    var expectedValue = "value";
    service.Setup(s => s.DoSomething(out expectedValue));

    string actualValue;
    service.Object.DoSomething(out actualValue);
    Assert.AreEqual(actualValue, expectedValue);
}
```

But when I tried the code that I actually want to run I cannot get it to work.
This is included below.

The interface

```
Public Interface IGetValue
    Function GetValue(ByRef myBoolOfInterest As Boolean) As Single
End Interface
```

The code I wish to test

```
Public Class ClassToBeTested

    Dim isProblem As Boolean

    Public Function PassComparisonValues(m_GetValueGetter As IGetValue) As    Boolean

        Dim dPBar As Single = m_GetValueGetter.GetValue(isProblem)

        Return isProblem
    End Function
End Class
```

The code that I have written to test this is below (Note - this is a different project).

```
public void MethodToTest()
{
     // Arrange
     // System Under Test
     ClassToBeTested myClassToBeTested = new ClassToBeTested();

     // Construct required Mock
     Mock<IGetValue> myMock = new Mock<IGetValue>();
     bool isProblem = true;
     myMock.Setup(t => t.GetValue(ref isProblem));

     // Act
     isProblem = myClassToBeTested.PassComparisonValues(myMock.Object);

     // Assert
     Assert.That(isProblem, Is.EqualTo(true));
}
```

What I want is to be able to control the contents of isProblem in ClassToBeTested, and i am finding that this is not happening.
It contains false no matter what I do.

Hope someone can help.

Comment: I would ask the library author.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is to make `isProblem` protected in the `ClassToBeTested`. Then just for the unit tests inherit from `ClassToBeTested` and set the value of `isProblem` to expected value.

```
class ClassToBeTested
{
    protected bool isProblem;
    // code here ...
}

class TestableClassToBeTested 
    : ClassToBeTested
{
    public TestableClassToBeTested(bool isPRoblemValue)
    {
        isProblem = isPRoblemValue;
    }
}

public void MethodToTest()
{
    // Arrange
    // System Under Test
    bool isProblem = true;
    ClassToBeTested myClassToBeTested = new TestableClassToBeTested(isProblem);

    // code here ...
}
```