# How to set the value of an out parameter Mocked in Moq within the "Return"?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, mocking, moq

I've some trouble while configuring my Moq.

I've a mockup with a method that has out parameter. This out parameter is really used, and I need to populate it with some meaningful value depending on the parameter I receive.

Currently, I've been unable to do this, is it possible? How?

Here is my current status:

```
Mock<IMyMock> _mock = new Mock<IMyMock>();
bool someFlag= false;
_mock.Setup(m=>m.GetSomething(It.IsAny<DateTime>(), It.IsAny<DateTime>(), out someFlag))
     .Returns((DateTime start, DateTime end, bool someFlagInternal)=>{
        IEnumerable<SomeOtherClass> otherClasses = GenerateMockedData(start, end);
        //Assign something to someFlag, depending on start and end
        someFlag=true;//This has no effects
     }) ;
new SomeController(_mock.Object);
```

In my `SomeController`, on a specific method, my real-non-mocked code calls it:

```
public class SomeController{}
    private IMyMock _someObjectThatWeDontKnowIsAMock;
    public SomeController(IMyMock someObjectThatWeDontKnowIsAMock) {
        _someObjectThatWeDontKnowIsAMock= someObjectThatWeDontKnowIsAMock;
    }

    private void ComputeNext() {
        Tuple<DateTime, DateTime> times = ComputeNextTimes();
        bool hasOverlap;
        IEnumerable<SomeOtherClass> otherClassesInstances = _someObjectThatWeDontKnowIsAMock.GenerateMockedData(times.Data1, times.Data2, out hasOverlap);
        if(hasOverlap) {
            //...
        }
    }
}
```

Every time I call my mock, it seems to returns the first value of `someFlag`, even if it is a static field that I modify.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Assigning out/ref parameters in Moq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068095/assigning-out-ref-parameters-in-moq)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem you are having is because the instance of the out parameter in the setup is different to the instance actually being used when exercising the test.

Taken from [Moq Quickstart](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart) documentation

> callbacks for methods with `ref` / `out` parameters are possible but require some work (and Moq 4.8 or later)

Create a delegate to handle the mock invocation.

```
 delegate IEnumerable<SomeOtherClass> GetSomethingCallback(DateTime start, DateTime end, out bool someFlag);
```

In the setup use `It.Ref<Bar>.IsAny` for the `out` parameter and use the delegate in the `Returns` expression.

```
mock
    .Setup(_ => _.GetSomething(It.IsAny<DateTime>(), It.IsAny<DateTime>(), out It.Ref<bool>.IsAny))
    .Returns(new GetSomethingCallback((DateTime start, DateTime end, out bool someFlag) => {
        IEnumerable<SomeOtherClass> otherClasses = GenerateMockedData(start, end);
        //Assign something to someFlag, depending on start and end
        someFlag = true;
        return otherClasses;
    }));
```

The `It.Ref<bool>.IsAny` instructs the returns delegate to interact with the instance reference of the actual object that was passed into the mocked member.

Comment: I was having the 4.7.x and it was not available to me. Now with the 4.8 and your solution it works like a charm! Thank you very much