# How to mock a method that returns void but modifies the reference type passed in?

Tags: c#, mocking

I have an interface like -

```
public interface ILedgerStoreRepository
{
    void AddInvoiceDetailsToBatchWriteObj(ref BatchWrite<InvoiceDetailsDAO> batchWriteDetails,
        ref InvoiceDetailsDAO invoiceDetails);
}
```

I want to mock this function in such a way that I only want to validate **invoiceDetails** value as my validation. Currently I'm trying it like -

```
    var repoMock = new Mock<ILedgerStoreRepository>();
    repoMock.Setup(m =>
        m.AddInvoiceDetailsToBatchWriteObj(ref batchWriteObj1,
            ref It.Ref<InvoiceDetailsDAO>.IsAny)).Callback<BatchWrite<InvoiceDetailsDAO>, InvoiceDetailsDAO>(
        (write, dao) =>
        {
            Assert.Equal(LedgerStoreTestConstants.TestInvoiceDetailsMappingDao, dao);
        }).Verifiable();
```

But it's throwing me the following error -

> System.ArgumentException
> Invalid callback. Setup on method with parameters (ref BatchWrite, ref InvoiceDetailsDAO) cannot invoke callback with parameters (BatchWrite, InvoiceDetailsDAO).

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: You need to use a custom delegate type to achieve this.
Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47723362/5950070)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have slightly modified the input parameters to be able to test it.

```
public interface ILedgerStoreRepository
{
        void AddInvoiceDetailsToBatchWriteObj(ref List<string> batchWriteDetails, ref string invoiceDetails);
}

public class TestClass
{
    public void Execute(ILedgerStoreRepository repo)
    {
        List<string> a = new List<string> { "Test", "Alpha" };
        string b = "Alpha";
        repo.AddInvoiceDetailsToBatchWriteObj(ref a, ref b);
    }
}

// You need this delegate
delegate void AddInvoiceCallback(ref List<string> batchWriteDetails, ref string invoiceDetails);

[Test]
public void DummyTest()
{
    var repoMock = new Mock<ILedgerStoreRepository>();
    repoMock.Setup(m =>
                     m.AddInvoiceDetailsToBatchWriteObj(ref It.Ref<List<string>>.IsAny,
                                                              ref It.Ref<string>.IsAny))
                .Callback(new AddInvoiceCallback((ref List<string> batch, ref string details)
            =>
            {
                Assert.That(batch.Contains("Test"));
            })).Verifiable();

    // Act   
    new TestClass().Execute(repoMock.Object);
}
```