# How to setup method out parameter to return mock in c#

Tags: c#, moq, out

I have service mock, which calls method, where one of parameters is out parameter.
How is it possible to out mocked object as this parameter, because I need to set up this mock further.

```cs
var randomObjectMock = new Mock<ISmth>(MockBehavior.Strict);
mock.Setup(x => x.DoSomething(out randomObjectMock);
```

```cs
ISmth randomObject;
var randomObjectMock = new Mock<ISmth>(MockBehavior.Strict);
mock.Setup(x => x.DoSomething(out randomObjectMock);`
```

Initialization randomObject is not an option.

```cs
Mock<ISmth > randomObject;
mock.Setup(x => x.DoSomething(out randomObjectMock.Object);
```

This also not an option.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068095/assigning-out-ref-parameters-in-moq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this should work:

```cs
var randomObjectMock = new Mock<ISmth>(MockBehavior.Strict);
var smth = randomObjectMock.Object;
mock.Setup(x => x.DoSomething(out smth));
```