# Moq Unit testing for ref parameter

Tags: unit-testing, moq

Is it possible to write unit testing for a method with multiple ref parameters(6). I tried with callback but didn't works. Can you please tell me some solution

Comment: Maybe you should have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/726630/verify-value-of-reference-parameter-with-moq

Comment: Unfortunately this is not possible with Moq. As the above SO answer there are alternative ways.